# PHP - Script don't finish via shell_exec when passing session_id

Tags: php, session, shell-exec

Hy guys,

if I call a php script via shell_exec and pass the session_id via parameters, the called php script is not terminated if I call the session_id with "session_id(previous_session_id);" and "start_session();" in the second script.
The second script stops at point "session_start();"

**Script 1 (executer.php)**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $sessionID = session_id();
  $return = shell_exec('php '.__DIR__.'/job.php sessionID='.$sessionID);
  print_r($return);
?>
```

**Script 2 (job.php)**

```
<?php
  parse_str($argv[1], $params); //Get params
  
  session_id($params['sessionID']); //Set the previous session_id
  session_start(); //Start the previous session 

  $returnValues = array('Submitted Arguments'=>$argv);
  print_r($returnValues);
?>
```

Can you please help me?

i tried also with session_write_close();

Comment: "i tried also with session_write_close();" How?

Comment: Do sessions work via CLI?

Comment: @HonkderHase : I'm an idiot. I tried with "session_write_close()" on the wrong postion. I put it before exec call and now, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. I tried with `session_write_close()` on the wrong position. I put it before exec call (job_executer Script) and now, it works :)

Comment: Why is it in the wrong position? The code in the question does not even use it.